# Why is the regex function to remove non-alphabetical character in a string not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, function, methods

I'm trying to do a challenge, I managed to succeed it, but it doesn't work the way I want to in one case..

Here's the challenge : `Given a string, return whether or not it forms a palindrome ignoring case and non-alphabetical characters.  Note: a palindrome is a sequence of characters that reads the same forwards and backwards.  Ex: Given the following strings... "level", return true "algorithm", return false "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama.", return true`

And here's my code:

```
import re

def isPalindrome(str):

    reversedString = re.sub(r'[^a-z]', '', str)
    reversedString = str[::-1]
    if reversedString == str:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

So, when I type for instance 'level', it does return true, when I type algorithm is does return false, but the problem is that the third example in the question still prints out false, while because it is an actual Palindrome, it should return false. It is a Palindrome if we take all the non-alphabetical characters out, such as points, commas, and columns.
So I naturally looked through the internet to see how we could possibly do that, found out that doing this using regex is the most efficient method, so I implemented it into my function.
The problem is, because there's always one, it actually runs like the regex method doesn't exist at all, it basically doesn't remove the non-alphabetical characters, while it should..
So, here I came to know what I possibly did wrong and if I could potentially get someone's help, because I've been stuck on it for a day now.

Thank you all for reading this !

Comment: do not use `str` as variable name, you are hiding the built in `str()`

Comment: Hint: where are you ignoring the case?

Comment: Several issues here:
1) Your regex does not include capital letters. So in the Panama example, it strips out the uppercase "P".
2) Add print statements to see what is happening to your reversedString variable - the line that applies the regex isn't actually doing anything. If you start debugging with more prints and fix the case issue, I think you'll be able to figure it out!

Comment: Yup I did try to debug and found some possible solutions, thank you guys for your help, really helped me out.

Comment: @marw4ne Note that it's a bad practice to name your variables the existing names of built-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your regex would be removing upper-case letters. Even if you modified the regex to remove both non-upper and non-lower-case letters, you are clobbering your results (`reversedString`) in the very next line of code.

You really need to first convert the input string to either all lower case or all upper case (lower case really since you are removing non-lower-case letters), since your input is a mixture and your palindrome will not read the same forwards and backwards unless you do so.

```
import re

def isPalindrome(str):

    str = str.lower()
    filteredString = re.sub(r'[^a-z]', '', str)
    reversedString = filteredString[::-1]
    if reversedString == filteredString:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

>>> isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama.")
True
```

Comment: Everything makes sense now, thank you so much for helping !

Comment: Oh okay just realized I could do that, just did it ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues with your current approach, make the main`reversedString` lowercased after replaceing not alphanumeric characters and then make `str` from `reversedString` not from it's own before comparing `reversedString == str`, I've slightly changed the code block, but same logic should work with your own version also.

```
import re

def isPalindrome(str):

    reversedString = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\\s]', '', str).lower()
    str = reversedString[::-1]
    if reversedString == str:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
        
isPalindrome('A man, a plan, a canal: Panama.')
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/GBLTM37163

Comment: *ignoring case and non-alphabetical characters* Why are you including numbers?

Comment: Why are you printing the function when the function doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()` to remove all the non alphabetical characters:

```
import re

def isPalindrome(s):
    s = re.sub('[\W\d_]','',s).lower()
    if s == s[::-1]:
        return True
    return False

print(isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama."))
print(isPalindrome("algorithm"))
print(isPalindrome("level"))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```